# mp3gain: Can't open mp3 for reading

Tags: linux, mp3, ubuntu-20.04

I regularly download mp3 files from different sources but a few months ago I began to get the error:

```
Can't open 1.mp3 for reading
```

when I tried to execute:

```
mp3gain -s s 1.mp3
```

Is the utility still maintained? I can hardly imagine that something is wrong with my system.

I'm using **version 1.6.2**

I tried to re-install the tool, but the problem remained

```
sudo snap remove mp3gain
sudo snap install mp3gain
```

Here are some outputs from the terminal

Playing with MPlayer:

```
$ mplayer 001.mp3 
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-9 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing 001.mp3.
libavformat version 58.29.100 (external)
Audio only file format detected.
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [mpg123] MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III
AUDIO: 32000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 48.0 kbit/4.69% (ratio: 6000->128000)
Selected audio codec: [mpg123] afm: mpg123 (MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 32000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
A:  16.3 (16.3) of 28.0 (28.0)  0.1% 

Exiting... (Quit)
```

Using file utility to get the file information:

```
$ file 001.mp3 
001.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 48 kbps, 32 kHz, Monaural
```

And finally using mp3gain to get the volume level:

```
$ mp3gain -s s 001.mp3 
001.mp3
Can't open 001.mp3 for reading
```

Comment: Are you currently playing the file? Could it be that it is being scanned by your virus scanner? Do you get the same error if you wait 15 minutes and try again?  How certain are you that these really are valid mp3 files? (Hint: opening them in VLC and going to tools -> media information can show if they are mp4 files with an mp3 extension)

Comment: @Mokubai I'm not playing the file while I run the command. I don't have a virus scanner (I'm using Linux). All the files can be played back with different players (e.g. MPlayer or VLC). I can also play them on Android.

Comment: Most media players will play an mp4 that is *named* as an mp3 as they will check the actual file data. My last point was asking to check that it is a *real* mp3 file that mp3gain would understand. Being able to play it is largely irrelevant to what the actual data is as mp3gain *only* understands mp3 while media players understand a whole lot more formats.

Comment: @Mokubai Ah ok. I understand. But as I said I've always downloaded mp3 files regularly from different sources and used mp3gain to check the volume level and to increase it if necessary. But few months ago mp3gain just began failing on these tasks. So the files mustn't be a problem. I've just tried to run it on the files that I downloaded years ago and got the same error...

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it is broken. Can't open any mp3 file I have.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is here: https://github.com/dodeco/snap-mp3gain/issues/2

In short, it can't open files that are on other filesystems. Copy them to your usual filesystem and it should work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Might be. I still think my answer is useful, and as far as I can see, it follows all the rules. If anybody wants to reformulate the answer, be my guest.